# Calculation to get decimal with 6 decimal places in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a division formula to get 6 decimal places for a new column.

```html
dt                      LD_VOY_N  LD_VSL_M
2017-04-29 12:00:00.000  0014S   rmhp tpcp 
2017-04-29 16:00:00.000  0014S   rmhp tpcp 
2017-04-29 20:00:00.000  0014S   rmhp tpcp 
2017-04-30 08:00:00.000  0014S   rmhp tpcp 
2017-04-30 12:00:00.000  0014S   rmhp tpcp 
2017-01-05 04:00:00.000  0014S   rmhp tpcp 
2017-01-05 08:00:00.000  0014S   rmhp tpcp 
2017-01-05 12:00:00.000  0014S   rmhp tpcp 
2017-02-05 04:00:00.000  0014S   rmhp tpcp 
2017-02-05 08:00:00.000  0014S   rmhp tpcp 

x                 y
12  126
16  110
5    105
3    102
1    101
13  88
26  62
5   57
39  18
18  0
```

I am trying to divide the x column by the y column, however, when I do this, the output is not correct. Below is the code that I am working on.

```html
SELECT dt, LD_VOY_N, LD_VSL_M , x,y, ISNULL(x/ NULLIF((y),0),0) as conditional_probability
```

Below is a sample of my output.

```html
dt                      LD_VOY_N  LD_VSL_M
2017-04-29 12:00:00.000  0014S   rmhp tpcp 
2017-04-29 16:00:00.000  0014S   rmhp tpcp 
2017-04-29 20:00:00.000  0014S   rmhp tpcp 
2017-04-30 08:00:00.000  0014S   rmhp tpcp 
2017-04-30 12:00:00.000  0014S   rmhp tpcp 
2017-01-05 04:00:00.000  0014S   rmhp tpcp 
2017-01-05 08:00:00.000  0014S   rmhp tpcp 
2017-01-05 12:00:00.000  0014S   rmhp tpcp 
2017-02-05 04:00:00.000  0014S   rmhp tpcp 
2017-02-05 08:00:00.000  0014S   rmhp tpcp 

x                 y           divided
12  126             0
16  110             0
5    105             0
3    102             0
1    101             0
13  88              0
26  62              0
5   57              0
39  18              0
18  0               2
```

Below is my desired output.

```html
dt                      LD_VOY_N  LD_VSL_M
2017-04-29 12:00:00.000  0014S   rmhp tpcp 
2017-04-29 16:00:00.000  0014S   rmhp tpcp 
2017-04-29 20:00:00.000  0014S   rmhp tpcp 
2017-04-30 08:00:00.000  0014S   rmhp tpcp 
2017-04-30 12:00:00.000  0014S   rmhp tpcp 
2017-01-05 04:00:00.000  0014S   rmhp tpcp 
2017-01-05 08:00:00.000  0014S   rmhp tpcp 
2017-01-05 12:00:00.000  0014S   rmhp tpcp 
2017-02-05 04:00:00.000  0014S   rmhp tpcp 
2017-02-05 08:00:00.000  0014S   rmhp tpcp 

x                 y           divided
12  126             0.095238
16  110             0.145454
5    105             0.047619
3    102             0.029411
1    101             0.009900
13  88              0.147727
26  62              0.419354
5   57              0.087719
39  18              0.461538
18  0               0
```

Do you any of you have ideas on how to get the desired output? Please do help as I have been stuck here for quite some time.

Comment: Convert `x` and `y` to `decimal(12, 6)` prior to dividing them

Comment: I agree with HoneyBadger. `x` and `y` are probably `ints`, so SQL server does an integer division.

Comment: have you tried to use `ROUND('yourdivision', 6)` or something?

Comment: Try this: `select cast( cast(x as decimal)/cast(y as decimal) as decimal(12,6))`

Comment: Hi, I have tried that and it gives me a "divide by zero error encountered"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
declare @tbl table(
x int,
y int
)

insert into @tbl(x,y)
values
(12,126),
(16,110),
(18,0)
;

SELECT x,y, 
case when y = 0 then 0
else
 round((cast(x as decimal(12,6)) / cast(y as decimal(12,6))), 6)
 end as divided

from @tbl
```

Before dividing, cast int values to `decimals`, and then `Round` the final result value to `6` decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
create table #testa ( x int , y int )
```

`insert into #testa (x,y) values (12,126)
select x,y , cast(cast (x as float)/cast (case when isnull(y,0) =0 then 1 else y end as float) as decimal(19,6)) from #testa`

Thank you